# DTD elements and repeating elements

Tags: xml, dtd

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <sensor-system>
     <velocity>120.00</velocity>    <!-- km/h --> 

     <temperature location="inside">24.6</temperature> 
     <temperature location="outside">-12.5</temperature> 

     <seats>

       <seat location="front">
               <id>1</id> 
                <temperature>32.5</temperature>
               <heating-is-on/>

       </seat>

       <seat location="back">
               <id>2</id>
                <temperature>23.5</temperature> 
        </seat>

     </seats>
   </sensor-system>

   <!-- degree celsius -->
```

There is exactly one velocity element inside the sensor-system element, followed by exactly two temperature elements with a mandatory location attribute. The mandatory seats element contains on ore more seat elements. There is exactly one id and one temperature element inside a seat element, followed by an optional heating-is-on element. The heating- is-on element has an empty inner content. All attributes are mandatory. The only allowed location values for the temperature element after the velocity element are ”inside” and ”outside”. The only allowed location values for the temperature element inside the seat element are ”front” and ”back”. The id elements contain integer numbers.

### Is that DTD correct:

```
 <!ELEMENT sensor-system (velocity,temperature+,seats)>
 <!ELEMENT velocity (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT temperature (#PCDATA)>
 <!ATTLIST temperature location (inside|outside) #REQUIRED>

 <!ELEMENT seats (seat+)>
 <!ELEMENT seat (id, temperature , heat-is-on?)>

 <!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT heat-is-on EMPTY>
 <!ATTLIST seat location (back|front) #REQUIRED>
```

My main 2 questions :

---

1-he said temperature to occur exactly twice , but i cant write 
          (

```
  <!ELEMENT sensor-system (velocity,temperature,temperature,seats)>
```

....so it will have to be temperature+ ??

2-temperature is declared again in seat ...but there's no need to write 
(

```
<!ELEMENT temperature (#PCDATA)>
```

again right ? cuz we already wrote it above

thank u

Comment: Why can you not write `(velocity, temperature, temperature, seats)` ?

Answer (score 1):

*temperature is declared again in seat ...but there's no need to write*

Correct.

*[...] temperature to occur exactly twice , but i cant write*

Yes, you can :-)

```
<!ELEMENT sensor-system (velocity,temperature,temperature,seats)>
```

is perfectly okay.  But quite likely there are other problems.

You probably want one inside temperature and one outside temperature.  You will not be able to enforce that with the current structure (i.e. through attributes).

Furthermore, making the location attribute mandatory means that it will also have to be specified in the `<temperature>` subelements of `<seat>`, where values of `inside` or `outside` make no sense. (The DTD formalism does not permit atttribute declarations or content models to vary according to context: all declarations are "global" in scope.)

A location attribute on the `<temperature>` element seems to be a poor design choice.  You could drop the attribute and try something like this instead:

```
<!ELEMENT sensor-system (velocity,inside,outside,seats)>
<!ELEMENT inside (temperature)>
<!ELEMENT outside (temperature)>
```

which seems to better reflect your requirements.

*Is that DTD correct*

The DTD is structurally consistent and grammatically correct.  But it doesn't match the spec statement.  First, there is a minor issue of spelling: `heating-is-on` versus `heat-is-on`.  Second, and much more important, is the business with the `location` attribute.  Putting it on the `<seat>` element was a sensible thing to do, but the spec statement has:

```
The only allowed location values for the temperature element after the velocity element are ”inside” and ”outside”. The only allowed location values for the temperature element inside the seat element are ”front” and ”back”.
```

This is not specifiable in the DTD formalism.  All structural constraints (such as, in this case, the permissible values of an attribute) are "global" in scope.